# the_content() is showing outside the div

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using the following function to show content. The content is showing properly but outside of the div.

```
<?php
function show_post(){
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'circular', 'post_per-page' => -1));

if($query->have_posts()){
    while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();

        $circular_slider .= '<div class="ca-item ca-item-1"><div class="ca-item-main"><div class="ca-icon"></div><p>';
        $circular_slider .= ''.the_content().'';
        $circular_slider .= '</p></div></div>'; 
    }
}   
wp_reset_postdata();
return  $circular_slider;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please share your *rendered* HTML and CSS code.

Comment: What is the content of ``the_content()``?

Comment: when I use specific text, it is showing properly but when using the_content(), it is showing outside of the div. Is this problem with HTML or CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`the_content` outputs the content directly – you want to use `get_the_content` instead, because that *returns* the content.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Alternative_Usage

Comment: Don’t forget to take into account what it says there about this function returning the _unfiltered_ content.

Answer (score 0):

Give the style property `-ms-word-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word;`

```
.ca-item .ca-item-1 {
    line-height:enter code here 1.6em;
    margin: 0.4em 0;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```